Force certain apps to use grayscale
I have a Google Pixel 6 with Android 14.
Currently I have enabled:
Settings > Accessibility > Color and motion > Color correction > Grayscale
But I find myself wanting to disable Grayscale (re-enable color) for certain apps, such as Google Maps.
This question All Internet apps in grayscale got my hopes up, but I don't see anything helpful in Settings > Apps > Digital Wellbeing.
How could I choose via an allow-list and/or deny-list which apps should or shouldn't use Grayscale mode?
If Android doesn't offer this feature natively, how (as a software engineer) could I code it for myself?
